# Merge two dataframes with interval of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to merge them but put th the value of one of the dataframes in the other. How can I do it?

Dataframe 1:

| Date | dif |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | -5.0 |
| 2023-01-02 | -4.0 |
| 2023-01-03 | 0.0 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1.0 |

Dataframe 2:

| Porcentaje | Inc |
| --- | --- |
| -3.0 | 0.0 |
| 1.0 | 2.0 |

Result:

| Date | dif | Inc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | -5.0 | 0.0 |
| 2023-01-02 | -4.0 | 0.0 |
| 2023-01-03 | 0.0 | 2.0 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1.0 | 2.0 |

The result must be a merge between the two dfs by the interval of the dif an de Porcentaje. For example, if dif < -3.0 then Inc would be 0.0.

The dif never is going to be greater than the max value of porcentaje in this example = 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='dif'),
                    df2.sort_values('Porcentaje'),
                    left_on='dif', right_on='Porcentaje',
                    direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
         Date  dif  Porcentaje  Inc
0  2023-01-01 -5.0        -3.0  0.0
1  2023-01-02 -4.0        -3.0  0.0
2  2023-01-03  0.0         1.0  2.0
3  2023-01-04  1.0         1.0  2.0
```

You can avoid having the `Porcentaje` column by using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) first to match the key in `df1`:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='dif'),
                    df2.sort_values('Porcentaje')
                       .rename(columns={'Porcentaje': 'dif'}),
                    on='dif', direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
         Date  dif  Inc
0  2023-01-01 -5.0  0.0
1  2023-01-02 -4.0  0.0
2  2023-01-03  0.0  2.0
3  2023-01-04  1.0  2.0
```